# PHP - Simplexml, чтение файла

Tags: php, xml

Есть xml файл, который я хочу распарсить. Делаю я это так:

```
$get = file_get_contents('./1c.xml');
$arr = simplexml_load_string($get);
print_r($arr);
```

Получаю вот такой вывод:

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Группа] => Array
        (
            [0] => Первая       
        )
)
```

Хотя у меня файл содержит много элементов, вот чего часть:

```
<Каталог>
<Группа>Дом
    <Группа>Первая
        <Группа>Классика
            <Группа>Футбол
                <Номенклатура>
                    <Наименование>Футболка</Наименование>
                    <Цена>121</Цена>
                    <ЦенаСоСкидкой>121</ЦенаСоСкидкой>
                    <Цвет>Серый</Цвет>
                    <Размер>44</Размер>
                    <Материал/>
                    <Категория/>
                </Номенклатура>
```

Т.е. из-за того, что `<Группа>Первая` вот так записана, скрипт думает, что объект пустой.

Можно ли эту проблему как-то побороть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще у вас точка входа - Каталог.

Что бы получить "дом" необходимо написать так:

```
$arr->Группа->xpath("parent::*")
```

или  так `$arr[0]`

Получить "Первая"

```
$arr->Группа
```

Получить далее

```
$arr->Группа->Группа
```

И так далее...

```
$arr->Группа->Группа->Группа
```